# Free buffer with data

Tags: c++, qt

Im using this code to get data from QTcpSocket. I read data in buffer and then if I free it immediately its fine. But if I free it later the application crashes.
QtDocs says that I have to clean up memory with delete[] after using method readBytes

```
void Widget::slotReadClient()
{
    QTcpSocket* pClientSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QDataStream in(pClientSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
    for (;;)
    {
        if (!m_nNextBlockSize)
        {
            if (pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16))
            {
                break;
            }
            in >> m_nNextBlockSize;
        }
        if (pClientSocket->bytesAvailable() < m_nNextBlockSize)
        {
            break;
        }
      QString attribute;
     quint16 count=0;
      in>>count;//count of massives
     quint16 els=count;
     uint len=0;
     char** wkbs;
     if(count)
          wkbs=new char*[els];
     int j=0;
     char* buf=0;

      while(count)
      {
          in>>attribute;//description its ok
          buf=wkbs[j];
          buf=0;
          in.readBytes(buf,len);
          ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString::number(len));//length of buffer ok
          j++;
          count--;
          processGeom(buf);//data is OK
          //delete [] buf; if I use this it works
      }
      ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString::number(els));
      j=0;
      while(els)
      {
          buf=wkbs[j];
          delete[] buf;//here I get crash
          els--;
          j++;
      }
      delete[] wkbs;
      m_nNextBlockSize = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never assigning anything to `wkbs`, so you are trying to `delete[]` an *uninitialized* pointer!

```
buf=wkbs[j];
buf=0;
in.readBytes(buf,len);
```

Here, you are assigning to `buf` three times!  The first lines are absolutely pointless, since `readBytes` will overwrite the value in `buf`.  If you want to keep the allocated buffer, store it in `wkbs` after `readBytes`:

```
in.readBytes(buf, len);
wkbs[j] = buf;
```

Next you are attempting:

```
buf=wkbs[j];
delete[] buf;//here I get crash
```

With your original code, `wkbs[j]` is *uninitialized*, its value could be *anything*.  Deleting this pointer is unsafe.

Comment: Thank you very mach for explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
      in.readBytes(buf,len);
      ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString::number(len));//length of buffer ok
      j++;
      count--;
      processGeom(buf);//data is OK
```

Right. You are supposed to call `delete[]` on the buffer you get from `readBytes`. So of course it works.

```
      buf=wkbs[j];
      delete[] buf;//here I get crash
```

Right, because this code makes no sense. You are calling delete on one element of an array that was allocated as a unit. If you want to free the elements individually, you have to allocate them individually.

Presumably, what you wanted was this:

```
      in.readBytes(wkbs[j], len);
```

This will store the buffer that `readBytes` allocates with `new[]` in `wkbs[j]`, allowing you to `delete[]` it whenever you wish.